# Google QUERY Formula to include "All" from a dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 3 separate dropdowns to generate the following QUERY function in my Google Sheet:

```
    =QUERY('HISOP Training'!A2:D,"select A, B, C, D where A contains '"&M5&"' and C contains '"&M6&"' and D contains '"&M7&"' order by D asc", 1)
```

The dropdown in cell `M5` references to column `A:A` (the Branch). The dropdown in cell `M6` references to column `C:C` (the Employee). The dropdown in cell `M7` references to column `D:D` (the (Document). Column `B:B` is the date and there is no dropdown for this.

Each dropdown has a list which references to each column. Each dropdown also has the word "All". When "All" is selected I want every row to return in the QUERY depending on what is selected in the other 2 dropdowns. For example, if the Branch "New York" is selected in the `M5` dropdown and "All" is selected in the `M6` & `M7` dropdowns, I want all employees and all documents returned for New York.

I can't work out how to create `IF`/`AND` into the `QUERY`. Would really appreciate help.

Comment: You can cover your Query formula under If statement 

For example:

    `=If(M5 <>"All", QUERY('HISOP Training'!A2:D,"select A, B, C, D where A contains '"&M5&"' and C contains '"&M6&"' and D contains '"&M7&"' order by D asc", 1), QUERY('HISOP Training'!A2:D,"select A, B, C, D order by D asc", 1))`

you can add more if statement per your requirement. Share your google sheets for exact answers

Comment: What if M6 or M7 = All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(
  'HISOP Training'!A2:D,
    "select A, B, C, D "
  & IF(
      OR(M5 <> "All", M6 <> "All", M7 <> "All"),
          "where "
        & TEXTJOIN(
            "and ",
            True,
            IF(M5 <> "All", "A contains '" & M5 & "' ", ""),
            IF(M6 <> "All", "C contains '" & M6 & "' ", ""),
            IF(M7 <> "All", "D contains '" & M7 & "' ", "")
          ),
        ""
    )
  & "order by D asc",
  1
)
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo

Comment: Thank you kishkin - it works but doesn't return a result when "All" is selected in all 3 dropdowns

Comment: @McChief selecting 3 "All"s should result in a query `select A, B, C, D order by D asc` which should just give you everything. Could you share a sheet example where this problem could be reproduced?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - the result was at the bottom of my sheet. I will just add 'where D is not null'. Thank you very much for your help.