# QUERY with cell reference containing a number

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

The formula in cell H2 works fine but the same one in cell F2 does not.
[image]

Their difference is that in F2 the second parameter for the query is taken from the cells with numbers.

```
=QUERY($A$3:$D;"SELECT A,B,C,D
WHERE 
A = '"&$A$1&"'
AND
B = '"&$B$1&"'")
```

The Filter() is not an option because I do not need to display all columns.
I would be grateful for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numeric numbers in query do not require single quote wrapping

```
=QUERY(A3:D;
 "select A,B,C,D
  where A = '"&A1&"'
    and B = "&B1)
```

with filter you can use constructed {} arrays

```
=FILTER({A3:B\ D3:D}; A3:A=A1; B3:B=B1)
```

also note that your F2 formula will work if you set formatting of B column to **Plain text**

---

```
=QUERY(A2:D; 
 "select A,B,D 
  where "&TEXTJOIN(" and "; 1; "1=1";
    IF(A1="";; "A = '"&A1&"'");
    IF(B1="House";; "B = "&B1);
    IF(D1="";; "D = '"&D1&"'")); 1)
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AvTyiR6ePPoDHj25obpud_6a3Sr0cp25e2CbvtUdVC4/edit#gid=573763249)

Comment: An exhaustive answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: I went a little further using [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62423879/2578960) The goal is the same only instead of "All" I have "Street" and "House". 
QUERY(
$A$3:$D;
  "select A, B, C, D "
& IF(
  OR(A1 <> "Street"; B1 <> "House");
    "where  "
& TEXTJOIN(
            "and ";
            TRUE;
            IF(A1 <> "Street"; "A = '" & A1 & "' "; "");
            IF(B1 <> "House"; "B = " & B1; "")
          );
        ""
    )
  & "order by C asc"
) 
Unfortunately I get an endless loop, the rows start to be added rapidly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Yes of course, forgive me for not responding quickly, only now I got to the computer [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wBID29px6jA8EcpQ-HUaTQPmnvLymQgxYA4EBYerGL0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I'm not clear enough, sorry. I wanted to display 2 rows (2 and 4 houses) when selecting "Red" and "House" - this works.
When I select in [QUERY Ref Cell]Sheet3!A1 "Street" and in [QUERY Ref Cell]Sheet3!B1 "House" to display all 5 rows - in this case, I have an endless loop of adding rows. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wBID29px6jA8EcpQ-HUaTQPmnvLymQgxYA4EBYerGL0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @BorisBaublys answer and the sheet updated. see if it works now

Comment: Thanks, that's cool. So I did not understand why I have an infinite loop in the my formula. I would like to understand the reason. I will compare your working code and my non-working one, I hope I understand. I've seen similar behavior when using ARRAYFORMULA().