# Query with multiple cell reference for multiple conditions with a select all option in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a data sheet 'All Data'!A2:AX. I am working on a dashboard where I want to filter the data using cell references by multiple conditions like gender, Nature of disability, Age less and greater than, and educational qualification. I have been able to achieve that through the below formula

[These are the way I have tried to use drop downs used in the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F9eb.jpg)

```
= query(importrange("URL","'All Data'!A3:AX"), 
"Select Col2, Count(Col24)
Where Col3 = '"&'WMR FY'!$B$3&"' 
AND 
(Col14 = '" &'WMR FY'!T3&"'
   OR Col14 = '" &'WMR FY'!U3&"'
   OR Col14 = '" &'WMR FY'!V3&"'
   OR Col14 = '')
AND 
(Col11 = '" &'WMR FY'!T2&"'
   OR Col11 = '" &'WMR FY'!U2&"'
   OR Col11 = '" &'WMR FY'!V2&"'
   OR Col11 = '" &'WMR FY'!W2&"'
   OR Col11 = '" &'WMR FY'!X2&"'
   OR Col11 = '" &'WMR FY'!Y2&"'
   OR Col11 = '')
AND Col24 = '"&'WMR FY'!U4&"'
AND Col12 >= "&'WMR FY'!U5&"
AND Col12 <= "&'WMR FY'!U6&"
Group by Col2 
Order by Count(Col24)
Label Col2 'Center Code', Count(Col24) '"&'WMR FY'!U10&"'",0)
```

1. Here Col2 is the center code as there are multiple centers
2. Col24 is the nature of disability column from source data
3. Col11 is the Qualification
4. Col14 is the gender
5. Col24 = Nature of disability
6. Col12 = Age
7. 'All data'A3:AX is the source data

With the above formula I am able to populate the data based on selections. However
what I was trying to achieve was this - If I keep one section for example cells for gender blank, it should populate all the genders in line with my other selections of qualification, nature of Disability, etc. Instead if I leave Gender blank I am getting blank cells.

I tried to use an if statement but not sure if it will do the job.

FYI  : AND Col3 = '"&'WMR FY'!$B$3&"' is just taking reference of a finacial year.

Sorry if I have asked the question properly. This is the first time I am asking a question as normally I have been able to find solutions online. I am looking for a non appscript soltion.

Please let me know if you want me to create a dummy sheet and I will try to create it at the earliest.

I thought I found a solution but was not able to make it work. Heres the link to the solution I found
[Google QUERY Formula to include "All" from a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422291/google-query-formula-to-include-all-from-a-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "All Data!A3:AX"), 
 "select Col2,count(Col24)
  where 1=1 "&
 IF('WMR FY'!$B$3="",," and Col3 = '"&'WMR FY'!$B$3&"'")& 
 IF('WMR FY'!T3&'WMR FY'!U3&'WMR FY'!V3="",," and Col4 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'WMR FY'!T3, 'WMR FY'!U3, 'WMR FY'!V3)&"'")&
 IF('WMR FY'!T2&'WMR FY'!U2&'WMR FY'!V2&'WMR FY'!W2&'WMR FY'!X2&'WMR FY'!Y2="",," and Col11 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'WMR FY'!T2, 'WMR FY'!U2, 'WMR FY'!V2, 'WMR FY'!W2, 'WMR FY'!X2, 'WMR FY'!Y2, "^$")&"'")&
 IF('WMR FY'!U4="",," and Col24 = '"&'WMR FY'!U4&"'")&
 IF('WMR FY'!U5="",," and Col12 >= "&'WMR FY'!U5)&
 IF('WMR FY'!U6="",," and Col12 <= "&'WMR FY'!U6)&"
 group by Col2 
 order by count(Col24)
 label Col2'Center Code',count(Col24)'"&'WMR FY'!U10&"'", 0)
```